# Regex replace in a string that contains one substring and does not contain another substring

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text that looks like this:

```
[customer id = "1" name="Bob" ...]
[customer id="2" name="Adam" ...]
[customer id="3" ...]
[customer id = "4" name="Julia" ...]
```

I have a function that should add Name to the entry if Name is not specified:

```
string AddNameIfDoesNotSpecified(string text, string id, string name)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text,
                    $"id\\s*=\\s*\"{id}\"",
                    $"id=\"{id}\" name=\"{name}\"",
                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

This works except that it does replace even if there is a name specified. How do I change regex to check if there is `"name\\s*="` substring, and if it's there - do not do replacement?

Another thing that I need to implement is UpdatName method:

```
string UpdateNameIfSpecified(string text, string id, string oldName, string newName)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text,
                    $"id\\s*=\\s*\"{id}\" name\\s*=\\s*\"{oldName}\"",
                    $"id=\"{id}\" name=\"{newName}\"",
                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

It works, but if we have other attributes between `id` and `name` like:

`[customer id="5" gender="female" name="Marta" ...]`

it's not going to work, how do I make it work in C# using regex? Should I use groups?

**Examples:**

```
AddNameIfDoesNotSpecified("[customer id = \"6\" ...]", "6", "Alex") 
               // output: "[customer id=\"6\" name=\"Alex\" ...]"

AddNameIfDoesNotSpecified("[customer id =\"7\" gender=\"male\" name=\"Greg\" ...]", "7", "Eric") 
               // output: "[customer id=\"7\" gender=\"male\" name=\"Greg\" ...]"

UpdateNameIfSpecified("[customer id = \"8\" ...]", "8", "Sam", "Don") 
           // output: "[customer id=\"8\" ...]"

UpdateNameIfSpecified("[customer id = \"9\" name=\"Lisa\" ...]", "9", "Lisa", "Carl") 
           // output: "[customer id=\"9\" name=\"Carl\" ...]"

UpdateNameIfSpecified("[customer id=\"10\" gender=\"female\" name=\"Megan\" ...]", "10", "Megan", "Amy") 
           // output: "[customer id=\"10\" gender=\"female\" name=\"Amy\" ...]"

UpdateNameIfSpecified("[customer id = \"11\" name=\"Tim\" ...]", "11", "Timothy", "Andrew") 
           // output: "[customer id=\"11\" name=\"Tim\" ...]"
```

Comment: You have some data (key-value pairs) serialized as a string line. 1. Deserialize it to types your language understand, 2. Manipulate data in easy way with benefits provided by compiler of your language. 3.Serialize back to the formatted string line. Obviously you should have this kind of classes which represent your data, because your application use it somehow...

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, use a lookahead assertion

```
   $"id\\s*=\\s*\"{id}\"(?!.*?name\\s*=)",
   $"id=\"{id}\" name=\"{name}\" ",
```

For the second one, use a capture group

```
   $"id\\s*=\\s*\"{id}\"(.*?)name\\s*=\\s*\"{oldName}\"",
   $"id=\"{id}\"$1name=\"{newName}\"",
```

Check these strings look like a regex when constructed.

Also, be aware that `\s` will span newlines
(use `[^\S\r\n]` to avoid that)

and `.*?` won't span newlines ( use a dot-all modifier if you need it to).